# Restrict user on the basis of their role

Tags: java, jsp

I have put role in session from servlet

```
 session.setAttribute("role", role);
```

but in the jsp i want to restrict the content accoring to the user role.

```
<c:if test="${role.admin==true}">
    <th style="width:80px;">Edit</th>
    <th style="width:80px;">Delete</th>` `
    <th style="width:80px;">Status</th>
</c:if>
```

this is the source code i have tried to restrict using jstl tag but it wont work 
please help.
thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What is role a string or some object, if yes paste role class in question?

Comment: role is just a string. in my system there are two type of users one is admin and other is normal users. if admin is logged in into the system then he/she can do anything like edit, delete the others content but when normal users logged in into the system they can only see the post. i need to hide the edit, delete and status button for normal users in jsp page.

Comment: If role is just a string, then your check is wrong. "role.admin" doesn't sounds right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving you a very simple idea for what you want. You can modify it as per your requirements. If "role" is a string then after getting the value of role from session check the value.

```
if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {
    // code for admin
}
else if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("normalUser")) {
    // code for normal user
}
```

Here "role" is not an object so you cannot use `role.admin=="true"`.

**EDIT:**

In EL you can code like:

```
<c:if test="${role eq 'admin'}">
    // for admin
</c:if>
```

and

```
<c:if test="${role eq 'normalUser'}">
    // for normal user
</c:if>
```

Comment: This is an example of a Java scriptlet, which is now a disapproved practise. This can be done using EL.

Comment: Yes, It should be done with EL.. This is just to give him an idea.